# Hunspell does not identify an obvious correct form of a misspelled word

Tags: emacs, hunspell

For the misspelled word "perapring" hunspell does not propose the correct spelling "preparing" and only proposes the following words:

```
persevering
pertaining
innerspring
preferring
preprint
wraparound
```

Is there a workaround that hunspell proposes "preparing", for example by modifying "default.aff" file? Any solution is welcomed.

Note: I am using "hunspell" through emacs.

Comment: Which OS do you use? If you don't have it installed already, I suggest you use [`aspell`](http://aspell.net/) instead of `hunspell`. See [Aspell and Hunspell: A Tale of Two Spell Checkers](https://battlepenguin.com/tech/aspell-and-hunspell-a-tale-of-two-spell-checkers/)